# Shouldn't it be possible to link two requestet topics in the documentation together?

Tags: feature-request, documentation

When I checked the Android requested topics I came across:
[QR Code reading](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/topic-requests/3795) and the use of the [Zxing QR & Barcode scanning lib](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/topic-requests/4569).
Personally I'd use ZXing to explain the QR Code reading, so it would be unnessecary to create two tutorials that cover the same topic.
Is there or will there be an option to link two requested topics if they could be explained by one example?

Comment: Or move a topic inside the other (at least the examples) so one of the not to be duplicate or unnecessary. Don't you think this could help?

Comment: Yeah, something like this would be helpful